# Установка Numpy для Python2

Tags: numpy, linux-mint, python-2.7, python-3.6

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно установить Numpy для Python2 параллельно с Numpy для Python3?
ОС Linux Mint 18.3, Python 2.7 и 3.6.
При установке Numpy ставится под Python 3.6, и Python 2.7 его не видит.
Пробовала снести Numpy и поставить его для 2.7, но он всё равно встал под 3.6

Answer (score 0):

When you have more than one Python installed, it can be tricky to make sure that you install packages for the right Python. In your Python 2 notebook, you can do:

import sys
print sys.executable

which will tell you where Python is. You can then use this to install numpy (and any other packages):

/path/to/python2 -m pip install numpy

Comment: Светлана, это русскоязычный сайт, тут принято публиковать вопросы и ответы на русском.